# Дружественные функции

Tags: c++

Есть класс, в котором объявлена дружественная функция, я хочу её определить тут же, т.е. не выносить определение в .cpp файл, а определить её в самом классе. Этого почему-то не получается, один из аргументов является типом класса и в определении функции я не могу получить доступ к его приватным данным. Как это можно сделать?

```
#pragma once

#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
class CIterator
{
public:
    using self_type = CIterator;
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using pointer = T*;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    //      Properties for all category iterator
    //Copy and copy-assignable by compiller
    //Constructors in private part
    const self_type& operator++() // Pre-increment
    {
        m_p++;
        return *this;
    }

    const self_type operator++(int) //Post-increment
    {
        auto tmp = *this;
        m_p++;
        return tmp;
    }

    ~CIterator() = default;
    //------------------------------------

    //      Input\output Iterator
    //operator-> by compiller
    bool operator==(const self_type& p) const
    {
        return m_p == p.m_p;
    }

    bool operator!=(const self_type& p) const
    {
        return !(*this == p);
    }

    reference operator*() const
    {
        return *m_p;
    }
    //------------------------------------

    //      Bidirectional Iterator
    const self_type& operator--()
    {
        m_p--;
        return *this;
    }

    const self_type operator--(int)
    {
        auto tmp = *this;
        m_p--;
        return tmp;
    }
    //------------------------------------

    //      Random Access Iterator
    const self_type& operator+=(ptrdiff_t size)
    {
        m_p += size;
        return *this;
    }

    const self_type& operator-=(ptrdiff_t size)
    {
        return *this += -size;
    }

    friend const self_type operator+(ptrdiff_t size, const self_type& p) //Can't define
    {
    /*
        Can't do, somethink like this, because "copy.m_p" not in scope, don'y know why.
        Similary to the other 4 friendly fucntion bellow.

        self_type copy = p;
        return copy.m_p + size;
    */
    }

    const self_type operator+(ptrdiff_t size)
    {
        return *this += size;
    }

    const self_type operator-(ptrdiff_t size)
    {
        return *this -= size;
    }

    const self_type operator-(const self_type& p)
    {
        auto copy = *this;
        copy.m_p -= p.m_p;
        return copy;
    }

    friend bool operator<=(const self_type& left, const self_type& right);
    friend bool operator>=(const self_type& left, const self_type& right);
    friend bool operator>(const self_type& left, const self_type& right);
    friend bool operator<(const self_type& left, const self_type& right);

    reference operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        return m_p[i];
    }
    //------------------------------------

private:
    CIterator()
        : m_p{ nullptr }
    {
    }

    CIterator(pointer p)
        : m_p{ p }
    {
    }

    pointer m_p;
};
```

Определяю всё в самом классе, потому что к сожалению не получается определить все функции в .cpp файле ибо это шаблонный клас и знаний как это сделать правильно у меня ещё нет.

Comment: вставьте пжлста участок кода в сам текст вопроса.

Comment: Приведите определение функции, которое не получается и лог сборки.

Comment: Дружественные функции определяются вне класса.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда зная объявление класса, можете предложить как определить одну из 5 дружественных ф-ций? У меня не получается это сделать из-за шаблона

Comment: Вставляйте шаблон перед функцией.

Comment: Да, этот очевидный способ мне известен, можете конкретный код продемонстрировать?

Comment: template<typename T>
bool operator<=(const T& left, const T& right) { // }

Comment: Это ведь шаблонный оператор сравнения, он не как не относится к классу который я написал. А что насчёт самой первой дружественной функции?

Comment: Так вы в классе должны указать какая функция вне класса будет для него дружественной, а потом вне класса определить ее. Я не понимаю вашей проблемы, почитайте про дружественные функции.

Comment: Еще раз: приведите лог сборки и недостающие куски кода (и уберите лишние), чтобы получился [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Дружественные функции можно определять и внутри класса, хотя это не всегда лучший вариант.

Comment: Код прекрасно компилируется (включая закомментированную часть), никаких проблем здесь нет. В чем вопрос??? Откуда вы взяли это "copy.m_p not in scope"?

Comment: @Виктор Садовин: Дружественных "шаблонных операторов" у вас в коде нет. Все дружественные операторы у вас *нешаблонные*.

Answer (score 0):

"Дружественность" не означает особого качества функции-члена класса, а отношение к внешней, по отношению к данному классу, функции (**глобальной** или члену **другого** класса), поэтому вопрос о возможности определения функции в теле класса, членом которой она не является, не имеет смысла. Дружественная функция (по отношению к заданному классу), означает, что эта функция имеет доступ ко всем закрытым и защищенным компонентам этого класса

Если нужно описать функцию в заголовке (.h) в котором определено тело класса, это можно сделать по следующей схеме:

```
//SomeClass.h
class SomeClass;
void someGlobalFunc(SomeClass *sc);

class SomeClass
{
friend void someGlobalFunc(SomeClass *sc);
void somePrivateFunc() {
//TODO: add your code here
}
int _n;

};


void someGlobalFunc(SomeClass *sc) {
sc->somePrivateFunc();
sc->_n = 0;
}
```

Для шаблонного класса соответственно шаблонная глобальная функция:

```
template <typename T>
void someGlobalFunc(SomeClass<T> *sc) {
//...
}
```

Comment: Совет определить дружественную функцию в целом правильный, однако (1) ничего не мешает определить ее сразу в теле класса `friend void someGlobalFunc(SomeClass *sc) {/*...*/}` (2) если нешаблонный вариант выносить наружу в заголовочном файле, то функцию следует объявить как `inline`, иначе при включении заголовочного файла в несколько единиц трасляции будут ошибки линковки (3) ОП не привел mcve, а в коде из вопроса явных проблем с отмеченной дружественной функцией вообще-то нет

Comment: "вопрос о возможности определения функции в теле класса, членом которой она не является, не имеет смысла." - это не верно. Существует даже более-менее устоявшаяся практика *всегда* определять дружественные функции в теле класса в целях единообразия (и по ряду другим причин).